# Published App But not showing in any device Accepts Destop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have published my app on play store but it is not showing in any device rather than Desktop pc..

if i go to the direct link of my app into any device it shows the same thing (**Your Device isn't compatible with this version**). what could be the cause..?

may be the problem is of checking the option(**PRICING & DISTRIBUTION->
CONSENT->Market opt-out**)option in the play store console or **in the manifest** file configuration settings in my project

i have tried a lot.. but i have not find any solution regarding this..

plz fix this issue as soon as possible
i have attached two images below.

**My Manifest File**

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lovecalculator.com.app.androidlocationmaps.lovecalculator"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">

<compatible-screens>

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SecondAct"
        ></activity>
</application>
```

**My Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "lovecalculator.com.app.androidlocationmaps.lovecalculator"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: add your manifestfile in question

Comment: added the manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is in this

```
   <compatible-screens>

<screen
    android:screenDensity="ldpi"
    android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="mdpi"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
    android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
    android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

A lot of the screens now do not come in this combination. Remove all these or tell me your requirement and i will help you write standard ones.

Comment: i just want to know that.. what are the main configuration settings do i need to support my app in all mobile devices and tablets as well..   In the manifest file and gradle..

Comment: Just remove that and check

Answer (score 0):

remove all `compatible-screens` tag from android manifest file and upload new APK on Google Play Store. its show in all devices.

***also check SUPPORTED DEVICES after upload new apk. you got count of supported devices***